# .htaccess remove numbers and extension from URL string

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I'm doing some reverse proxies for a blog and would like to achieve the following in my .htaccess file.

**Redirect Legacy URLs**

http://blog.domain.com/post-title-123.html

to

http://blog.domain.com/post-title/

I think I have to use the following piece of regex -[0-9]+.html to identify the part of the URL I wanted 'changing' to a /.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)-[0-9]+\.html$ /$1/
```

or if you already are using mod_rewrite and don't want rewritten URI's to get mangled by mod_alias, stick with mod_rewrite and add this **above** any routing rules that you may have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[0-9]+\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Used the standard mod_rewrite and it works a charm. Thanks Jon!